# Memory leaking in C, malloc inside function

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc

I am trying to create a 2d array of struct grid_t, and am getting memory leak warnings via address sanitiser, and eventually a seg fault in certain conditions.

There may be various points in my code causing this, but I thought knowing what was going wrong here would point me in the right direction to fixing the rest.

I am new to C and thus to memory management, so all feedback is welcome and appreciated!

```
void createGridArray(atom_t* ATOM) {
  ATOM -> grid = (grid_t**) malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(grid_t*));

  grid_t *nullGrid = malloc(sizeof(grid_t));
  grid_t temp = {NULL, 0};
  *nullGrid = temp;


  for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
    (ATOM -> grid)[i] = malloc(HEIGHT * sizeof(grid_t));
    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
        (ATOM -> grid)[i][j] = *nullGrid;
    }
  }
  //free(nullGrid); <- do I do this now?
  return;
}
```

Comment: `atom_t`, `grid_t`.. Are we supposed to know what those are? Post a [mcve].

Comment: [Please see this discussion on why not to cast the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917).

Comment: Yes - code without data and types is just confusing.

Comment: @SouravGhosh How do you manage to religiously paste that link on every post? Do you have like a hotkey combination set to paste that link?

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya yep, FN+C, FN+V. :P

Comment: @SouravGhosh Couldn't have guessed that. It would be worth while to just write a bot that scans the questions for (T*) malloc and pastes the link in the comments :p

Comment: `ATOM -> grid` is _not_ a 2D array.  It is a pointer to a pointer of `grid_t`. [example](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+**bar%3B).  Code cannot create an _array_ by using `malloc()`.  Code can allocate memory and get a pointer that is used like `ptr[i][j]`, but `ptr` is not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, don't cast the return from `malloc()`.   It is not required in C, and can obscure serious errors.

Second, don't hard-code the type into the `malloc()` call.   For example,

```
ATOM->grid = (grid_t**) malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(grid_t*));
```

would be replaced by

```
ATOM->grid = malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(*(ATOM->grid)));
```

This ensures the memory allocated is of the required size, regardless of what `ATOM->grid` is a pointer to.

To answer your question, to release all memory, you need to pass every non`NULL` pointer returned by `malloc()` to `free()`.  Exactly once.

So, if you allocate like this

```
ATOM->grid = malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(*(ATOM->grid)));

grid_t *nullGrid = malloc(sizeof(*nullGrid));
grid_t temp = {NULL, 0};
*nullGrid = temp;

for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
{
    (ATOM -> grid)[i] = malloc(HEIGHT * sizeof(*((ATOM->grid)[i])));
    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
        (ATOM -> grid)[i][j] = *nullGrid;
}
```

the one way of deallocating would be

```
for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++)
{
    free((ATOM -> grid)[i]);
}
free(ATOM->grid);
free(nullGrid);
```

In this case, you cannot safely `free(ATOM->grid)` before any         `free((ATOM -> grid)[i])` (unless you store all of the `(ATOM->grid)[i]` somewhere else, which sort of defeats the point).    The individual `(ATOM->grid)[i]` may be freed in any order (as long as each is released exactly once).

Lastly, check the pointers returned by `malloc()`.   It returns `NULL` when it fails, and dereferencing a `NULL` pointer gives undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why not simply `(ATOM -> grid)[i] = calloc(HEIGHT, sizeof(*((ATOM->grid)[i])));`? Now the loop to set it to zero isn't needed anymore (all problems gone).

Comment: The OP was using `malloc()` and initialising that way, not I.  So I simply explained how to clean up.     My tips are actually about preventing bugs.   There are plenty of other improvements possible in how the OP set things up - using `calloc()` is only one - but the question was not about that.

Comment: Thank you. Have removed casts, used calloc, and after a bit of fiddling have some working code

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to `free(nullGrid);` here to avoid a memory leak.

But actually you can simplify your code to this:

```
void createGridArray(atom_t* ATOM) {
  ATOM -> grid = (grid_t**) malloc(WIDTH * sizeof(grid_t*));

  grid_t nullGrid = {NULL, 0};

  for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
    (ATOM -> grid)[i] = malloc(HEIGHT * sizeof(grid_t));
    for (int j = 0; j < HEIGHT; j++) {
        (ATOM -> grid)[i][j] = nullGrid;
    }
  }
}
```

There is need for mallocing nullGrid here at all. BTW the `return` at the end of a void function is implicit.

You wouldn't do this either:

```
void Foo()
{
   ...
   int *temp = malloc(sizeof(int));
   *temp = ...;
   ...
      bar = *temp;

   ...
   free(temp);
}
```

but rather:

```
void Foo()
{
   ...
   int temp
   temp = ...;
   ...
      bar = temp;

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The C memory allocation is easier when you think it as a "loan".

Somehow, the system loan you some memory when you call malloc(), and you have to give it back with free().